# Jetty server stops running after closing terminal window

Tags: java, macos, jetty

I am a newbie when it comes to Java and Jetty app deployment. I use the default settings for setting up my jetty serve and ran `java -jar start.jar` on my terminal window. The server runs as expected, but when I close my terminal it stops. Is this normal? I used XAMPP before and there you can close the terminal without any problem. How do I overcome this problem, everybody needs to shut down there personal computer once in a while.

I'm using a mac btw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you're using ssh or something like that to start Jetty on a remote Linux/Unix server.

So, you can use `nohup java -jar start.jar &` - `nohup` will prevent your process from being stopped by the usual Unix "hangup" signal ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)) when you log out, and the `&` will put jetty as a background process so you can type `exit` or whatever to log out.

If you want to be able to re-attach to the Jetty terminal, I'd recommend reading up on [GNU screen](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/285795-taking-command-of-the-terminal-with-gnu-screen-).

If you want to stop jetty gracefully again, I'd really recommend using it as a service, or using `screen` to avoid losing the terminal.  But if it's too late for that you can find the PID in the output of `jps -l` and then call `kill $PID`.

Comment: Have you type any character wrong? I don't get it work, the server starts but I can't close my terminal. I'm using SSH btw, in Eclipse RSE terminal. I typed as you said `java -jar start.jar &`

Comment: with the `&`it runs this error first:
2011-03-02 21:45:10.165:INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.J
spServlet
2011-03-02 21:45:10.248:INFO::Logging to StdErrLog::DEBUG=false via org.eclipse.jetty.util.l
og.StdErrLog

Comment: And then I click any key and the server starts as normal

Comment: Thats not quite corret I guess. If you just & the process it is still bound to your terminal session. You have to decouple the process by the nohup command, like Dmytro mentioned.

Comment: try adding the full path of the start.jar. E.g. it is located at /opt/jetty - java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar &

Comment: Yep, sorry.  I added "nohup" to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

try "nohup java -jar start.jar &"

and i'm already say it in previous question )

Comment: Ok it worked now! Thanks really appreciate it. But how do I close it? Not that I need to close my server that much ,but do I run  `java -jar start.jar &` and `Ctrl + C`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up jetty to run as a service... here's the instruction for [linux](http://jawher.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/manually-installing-a-recent-version-of-jetty-as-a-service-in-linux/) and [windows](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/make-jetty-as-windows-service/). This way, you don't need to worry about launching jetty everytime through the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

How to kill process:

1) java style

when start jetty :

**java -DSTOP.PORT=8077 -DSTOP.KEY=secret_key_only_admin_know -jar start.jar**

for stop:

**java -DSTOP.PORT=8077 -DSTOP.KEY=secret_key_only_admin_know -jar start.jar -stop**

P.S. ports can be any - but they must be the same for start and kill commands :)

2) linux style

kill process by PID

Answer (score 1):

You can properly install it as a linux service(if you are actually connecting to a linux server) too.

cd to your jetty folder, for example mine is:

```
cd /home/spydon/jetty/
```

They have actually made most of the work with the jetty.sh file, so copy that one to /etc/init.d/

```
sudo cp ./bin/jetty.sh /etc/init.d/jetty
```

Then open the file with your favorite text editor, like vim or nano

```
sudo vim /etc/init.d/jetty
```

In the beginning simply uncomment(simply remove the hash(#)) three lines that says something like

```
 #chkconfig: 3 99 99
 #description: Jetty 9 webserver
 #processname: jetty
```

Meanwhile you have the text editor open, also add the jetty home directory to the beginning of the file, mine looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
#
# Startup script for jetty under *nix systems (it works under NT/cygwin too).
JETTY_HOME=/home/spydon/jetty

# To get the service to restart correctly on reboot, uncomment below (3 lines):
# ========================
 chkconfig: 3 99 99
 description: Jetty 9 webserver
 processname: jetty
# ========================
```

(You don't actually need to uncomment those three lines for it to work, only add the jetty_home. But for a proper deploy you should probably fix those lines.)

Now you should be able to start it with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start
```

And if you want it to run every time you boot, simply add

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/jetty /etc/rc1.d/K99jetty
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/jetty /etc/rc2.d/S99jetty
```

This should work for most modern distros, but I've only tried it on debian based ones.